# Using fetch to post cross-origin JSON data to Express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, fetch

I'm trying to use Fetch to post some JSON data from a form and log the response from the Express server, which should be a simple JSON response containing the posted form values, but I'm only receiving an empty object in the console.

The HTML and JavaScript can be executed from this [**JSFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/s9Lkejzd/).

How do I receive a populated JSON object response from the server?

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstName" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastName" />
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const form = document.getElementById("myForm");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/form-post", {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            body: {
                firstName: e.target.firstName.value,
                lastName: e.target.lastName.value
            } 
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data));
});
```

**Express Server**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const cors = (req, res, next) => {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type");

    next();
};

app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/form-post", (req, res) => {

    res
        .status(200)
        .json({
            First_Name: req.body.firstName,
            Last_Name: req.body.lastName
        });

});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server started on port 5000..."));
```

**[EDIT:]** It works fine in Postman (screen captures attached) but It doesn't seem to work with Fetch.

[image]

Comment: install bodyParser package and this line `var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); ``app.use(bodyParser.json());`
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't say there was a CORS error.  But I'm posting from jsfiddle to my localhost.

Comment: @PrashantGupta bodyParser.json() has been replaced with express.json() in Express 4, which is what I'm using.

Comment: How can jsfiddle send request to your localhost? Can you log something in your express `/form-post` endpoint to ensure that the request is received? Have you treid sending the request with `FormData` instead of Javascript object?

Comment: @choz yes it receives the request, but it logs an empty object `{}` with `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: I must've misread your post, sorry

Comment: @JaromandaX no problem :)

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 Can you try to post it with `FormData` like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9Lkejzd/10/) or with json-encoded data like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9Lkejzd/8/), and see if it works.

Comment: @choz !! Thanks!  Explicitly adding the content type (`headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }`) and stringifying the body (`body: JSON.stringify({
                firstName: e.target.firstName.value,
                lastName: e.target.lastName.value
            })`) works.  But now I'm left scratching my head as to why this works?!

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 Fetch's body needs to be exactly the same stype as the header's content-type. Now, I am not sure where I have read that, and what's the default header's content-type is. If I can recall it, I'll post it here.

Comment: @choz of-course!  I was passing an actual object as the body, which needed to be stringified to be a JSON object *facepalm*.  Good to know about the required header for fetch.  Please add your answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not `POST` a plain javascript object.

But, please do check all possible values of `Content-type` as defined in [RFC 1341](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1341) with the list of [mime types](https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html).

**According to MDN**

> [Fetch body data type must match "Content-Type"
> header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Try this code instead.

```
const form = document.getElementById("myForm");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  var data = {
    firstName: e.target.firstName.value,
    lastName: e.target.lastName.value
  }

  fetch("http://localhost:5000/form-post", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
});
```