# JavaScript POST request leads to empty request body on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building a simple financial app to practice my newbie JS skills. The client is running on localhost:3000 and the server is running on localhost:4001.

Client-side code:

```
async function addTransaction(id, date, description, header, amount) {
    await fetch('http://localhost:4001/transactions', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({id, date, description, header, amount})
    });
}
```

Server-side code:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});

function addTransaction(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
}

app.post('/transactions', addTransaction);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`));
```

I am aware that similar questions have been asked on this forum, but none of the given solutions, like adding `Content-type: application/json` to the header have worked for me.

Interestingly, making a post request from Postman is actually working.

I hope anyone can help.

Comment: What's the result without the JSON.stringify part on client side ?

Comment: Can you post the code you used to try and add the json header?

Comment: @TLd — `fetch` will implicitly call `toString()` on the object and post the string `"[object Object]"` (which is useless)

Comment: Duplicate: [Using fetch to post cross-origin JSON data to Express backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325363/using-fetch-to-post-cross-origin-json-data-to-express-backend)

Comment: Combining a `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` headers with cors middleware fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You failed to set a `Content-Type` request header so the default is being applied (`text/plain` IIRC).

Since the client hasn't *said* it is sending JSON, it doesn't trigger the JSON body parser you set up.

```
fetch('http://localhost:4001/transactions', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({id, date, description, header, amount})
});
```

Since that will turn the request into a preflighted request, you'll **also** need to configure your server to handle the preflight OPTIONS request before the client will make the POST request.

Currently you are rolling your own CORS handling:

> ```
> app.use((req, res, next) => {
>     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
>     next();
> });
> ```

**Don't** do that. Use [the `cors` middleware module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and follow the instructions to [configure it for preflighted requests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight).

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I tried specifying the Content-Type earlier, which didn't work. But since I combined that with using the CORS middleware, it's working! I am very happy :)